# Understanding the trajectory of a projectile

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, vectors, projectile

It is stated that a projectile's motion can be divided into individual vectors. Now according to the laws of physics, the forces acting in the y-direction will never cancel or affect the force acting in the x-direction. Hence the weight $mg$ and the horizontal force $F$ are independent of one another.

If that is the case, then why does a ball take longer to reach the ground if the horizontal force acting on it is large?

Imagine it this way, a ball machine shoots a ball with a great force in the x direction, then why is it that the ball takes longer to fall when the x component is so large? Shouldn't the force $mg$ cause a constant downward acceleration?

I understand that in case the x component is very large, the distance covered will naturally be greater but I'm speaking in terms of time taken for it to reach the ground.

Comment: You mix force and velocity.  But your example sounds - you shoot the ball (by using some force) and after, only gravitation works. The ball flies.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the time is longer when the horizontal force is large - could you elaborate why you think it is?

Comment: I tried throwing two objects, one vertically downwards and one horizontally straight towards the edge of my bed (Both had the same level of ground, in my case it was the bed) Every time I did it, the object I applied no force on in the x direction always fell faster.

Comment: How can you measure it so accurately? How do you know you were throwing truly horizontally? Were you by chance giving some vertical velocity to the one you "just dropped"?

Comment: I wasn't. I simply let it go from my hand. The difference in time wasn't very great but it was noticeable. I'm really sorry if I'm confusing two different concepts (in case I am) but let's take an example of a bullet fired from a gun.   What I want to know is, in case the time of falling is entirely dependent on the vertical component then does that mean that no matter what (in a basic system) the bullet will touch ground in one second? Considering I fire it from a height of roughly 10m.

Comment: If you [go high enough and apply enough force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_cannonball), your time to reach the ground will extend towards infinity.

Comment: Probably just that you actually unconsciously throw the object forward with some upward component for a lot of reasons, including that this is almost always more useful and that a true forward throw would appear to your observation to have an initial downward component so you compensate. The idea that objects in a vacuum fall at the same rate toward earth regardless of their horizontal velocity is one of the founding principles of kinematics. Though if you throw really really *really* hard, the curve of the Earth will cause it to take longer, but I would be surprised if this was the case here.

Comment: @Devsman Hahaha I'm pretty sure that wasn't the case. You're right, it must've been a blunder on my part. I very well understand where I was going wrong now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do take a look at [this video from the Harvard Physics Dept.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMF4CD7i3hg), which features a device specifically designed to drop a ball at the same time as it launches a ball.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a real projectile, there are two forces at work during the flight: gravity, and drag. Now drag is a *quadratic* force - that is, when you double the velocity, the force becomes four times greater:

$$F = \frac12 \rho v^2 A C_D$$

In this equation, $\rho$ is the density of the medium (air), $A$ is the projected area (cross section) of the object, $v$ is the velocity, and $C_D$ is the drag coefficient (a function of shape, and of Reynold's number). For a sphere we usually assume $C_D = 0.5$ but that is an approximation.

Now let's draw a diagram of a projectile in flight, having just "dipped" away from the horizontal direction. I draw the diagram for two different horizontal velocities, and compute the vertical component of the drag.

[image]

As you can see, the larger horizontal velocity gives rise to a larger vertical drag component - so if quadratic drag is present and non-negligible, the projectile will indeed fly further, and stay airborne longer.

Surprising, isn't it?

#### What about curvature

If you ignore drag, but include curvature of the earth, then the argument goes like this: if you shoot a projectile horizontally from height $h$ so it would normally land at a distance $D$ (on a perfectly horizontal surfaces), then the earth will have "curved away" a little bit in the meantime. How much? For small distances, we can calculate the "dip" $d$ as

$$\begin{align}d&=R(1-\cos\theta) \\
&\approx R\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{D}{R}\right)\right)\\
&\approx \frac{D^2}{2R}\end{align}$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle subtended between the start and end of the trajectory, seen from the center of the earth. When you shoot an object so it lands 100 m away, the curvature would add an additional 0.1 mm - negligible. Shoot 1 km, and it becomes 8 cm - still very little. Shoot 10 km, and the "dip" is 7.8 m, it would have a measurable effect on the time to drop. But compared to the drag effect, it is still very small.

Comment: +1 for answering the *letter* of the question instead of the *intent* of the question, which is based on the wrong assumption that fall takes longer for higher x-velocities ;)

Comment: @floris  wait a second- the force $F_d^y$ in y direction is always proportional to $v_y^2$, isnt it? So - if you throw a ball in a room, $v_y^2$ will always be almost nothing, independently of $v_x$. What do you think?

Comment: @jaromrax - no, the force is proportional to the total velocity squared, not the vertical component. The interesting corollary is that if you are riding your bike in a cross wind, it is harder work than having no wind (even though you think the wind is not "pushing you", as it is coming from the side). That's what I tried to demonstrate with my diagram. It's not intuitive.

Comment: @Floris - yes, while $v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$ the force  $F\neq F_x+F_y$. Then you come to $F_y\sim v^2 \sqrt(1-cos^2 \alpha)$. Good answer. Maybe one thing missing - rotation

Comment: @jaromrax - I did consider bringing in spin, and the effect it might have. But I did not want to introduce elements that were not implied in the original question. Obviously, the Magnus effect can influence the real-world answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the Earth to be flat, adding horizontal velocity (or force in your example) won't change how long it takes for the object to fall.

It covers more distance in the x direction in the same amount of time, because it has a higher velocity.

The time to fall depends only on gravity, because only gravity will make it fall.

If you have a very high horizontal velocity it will change the time it takes to fall, because then the Earth can't be approximated as flat over the distance you travel. As you move horizontally the Earth will curve further below you.  If you can balance the rate of falling with how fast you are going, you will orbit the planet instead of falling (which is what we do with satellites).  It's kind of like you're constantly falling forward so fast that you never reach the ground.

Note: This answer is assuming we are not considering drag (which may or may not be appropriate, it depends entirely on how basic you are assuming the system is.

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm trying to explain without mathematical calculations.**

First of all, the horizontal and vertical components work **independently**.

Secondly, the usual treatment is assuming the **magnitude** of the initial velocity is fixed.

Thirdly, the time of flights (assuming you projected the object from horizontal ground and it's landing on the ground at the same level) is the time requires to return at the same level.

So larger the angle of projection (from horizontal) means larger the vertical component of velocity; as a result, longer the time of flight.

Comment: You are answering a different question. OP says both instances have zero initial vertical velocity. You are talking about the case where projectiles are launched at different angles, with the same initial velocity. Good answer to a different question.

Comment: @Floris For quadratic drag, you may interested in another question [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150242/teenager-solves-newton-dynamics-problem-where-is-the-paper)

Comment: Thanks for that link - interesting. I particularly like that one of the answers given actually has a [link to the paper written by Shouryya Ray](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1283.pdf). Something for the weekend...

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not taking in consideration the resistance of the air, which is a fluid. That resistance adds a new force on the Y-axis which compensates the weight.

In a vacuum, the ball would reach the ground at the same time, for any X-axis speed.

Comment: The air drag does not compensate the weight, but is subtracted from it (anti-parallel vectors).

Comment: Isnt it the meaning of compensate? I'm not native English, it's the meaning of its traduction in my language...

Comment: If you use 'compensate', doesn't it mean that the total force is zero? In this case the drag lowers the weight but doesn't make it zero.

Comment: Actually it can compensate fully and even more, you sometimes see balls going a little higher and then falling because speed decreases too and drag isn't powerful enough anymore... You are right that I didn't mention the behaviour of the force depending on time though, I'll add something about it